# How to incorporate a page paging in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, html-table

I am in the process of learning with this framework (Vuejs) and I need to find a way to add a page in a table, by which, it should be expanded as more objects are added and then list them in the table and limit the number of items to show by tab.

The table used is the following.

```
  <table class="table table-responsive">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Título</th>
          <th>Tipo</th>
          <th>Categoría</th>
          <th>Fecha creación</th>
          <th>Acción</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr :key="post.IDEN_PUBLICACION" v-for="post in posts" v-if="!post.FLAG_VALIDADO && !post.FLAG_BAN">
          <td>{{post.NOMB_PUBLICACION}}</td>
          <td>{{post.CODI_TIPO_PUBLICACION == 'P' ? 'Producto' : 'Servicio' }}</td>
          <td>{{post.categoria.NOMB_CATEGORIA}}</td>
          <td>{{post.FECH_CREACION | dateFormat}}</td>
          <td>
            <a class="btn btn-success" @click="acceptPost(post)" title="Aceptar"><icon name="check"></icon></a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger" @click="ban(post)" title="Rechazar"><icon name="times"></icon></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Searching, I found that there are plugins that can help this time, but if I manage to implement it visually, I do not know how to start developing the behavior I need.

I try with 'vue-paginate'.

```
 <!--Paginación de tabla -->
      <template>
        <paginate
          :page-count="5"
          :page-range="1"
          :margin-pages="1"
          :click-handler="recorrerTabla"
          :prev-text="'Anterior'"
          :next-text="'Siguiente'"
          :container-class="'pagination'"
          :page-class="'page-item'">
        </paginate>
      </template>
```

this method I only used it to check functionality

```
methods: {
acceptPost (post) {
  controller.acceptPost(this, post)
},
recorrerTabla: function (pageNum) {
  console.log(pageNum)
},
```

n summary, I would like that the table shows 5 items per tab of the table and that the pager allows me to see in another tab the following 5 items. If this is possible, add that the number of pages fits the total of items, it would be great.

Image from the view

[image]

Technologies used:

Vuejs 2.4 Node 8+ Nuxt 1.0.0 - RC11 Nuxt / Axios 4.5.0 JWT-Decode 2.2.0 Js-Cookie Vee-Validate

In advance, thanks for your answers and any documentation or example of help.

Comment: So you want to be able to scroll and see all the items but also be able to paginate it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Images of code are not as useful as the text they contain because the images can not be searched, are not accessible, and are hard to read on smaller size screens. You can [edit] the question and insert the text and then format it as code by indenting it by four spaces.

Comment: thanks and sorry if the post is very bad haha ​​I think it expresses the desired best and edit the view of the code.